# Sql query, selecting on unique identifier gives - Error converting data type varchar to uniqueidentifier

Tags: sql, sql-server

How do I select a column of type uniqueidentifier when I have a guid?

I've tried doing following:

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE id = '442402e-207d-b012-4b60-005056c00123'

and 

SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE id = '{442402e-207d-b012-4b60-005056c00123}'
```

Both give me same error: Error converting data type varchar to uniqueidentifier.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The first query is ok, but you are missing a digit on the first part of the GUID, it should have 8 digits, not seven....something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE id = '71494DD6-90FB-417D-B9E2-28F34103C039'
```

Comment: duh. copy pasta error. thank your for noticing. NOW this error message makes sense.

Answer (score 6):

You are missing a digit in the first section

`4067876A-E3C3-4A3D-B2D3-E879474168C6` is a valid GUID
`442402e-207d-b012-4b60-005056c00123` is not