# Why does click tracking change my querystring GUID?

Tags: mailgun

When click tracking is enabled Mailgun re-writes our URLs as expected. However, we are seeing some URLs in the server logs (IIS) with the wrong guid.

For example,

MailGun tracks a click like this (from the log):

> Clicked: john.doe@testdomain.co.uk
>   http://portal.mybusiness.co.uk/redirect/?g=41E88BBB-CB7E-4BBF-BBB9-5ABBBEC58310

In our IIS logs we see this:

> 2016-11-17 08:20:38 123.456.78.123 GET /redirect/
>   g=41R88NOQ-PS7R-4O9S-NSR9-5NR71RP5831043|35|80040e07|Error_converting_data_type_varchar_to_uniqueidentifier.
>   80 - 1.23.456.7
>   Mozilla/5.0+(compatible;+MSIE+9.0;+Windows+NT+6.1;+WOW64;+Trident/5.0)
>   - 500 0 0 281

It looks like an error occurs during the re-write. Can anyone confirm? Is there an known issue?

Some click throughs are fine. Errors are on about 50% of the re-written URL clicks.

Answer (score 0):

Its'a 500 internal server error so I'd assume the error is further down the stack and the message `Error_converting_data_type_varchar_to_uniqueidentifier` would suggest it's a [SQL SERVER issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6022603/sql-query-selecting-on-unique-identifier-gives-error-converting-data-type-var), and the reason for this is that GUID you've included in the post from the IIS logs is [not valid](http://www.freecodeformat.com/validate-uuid-guid.php).

Therefore, to resolve, I'd switch up your guid generator

Comment: This is still happening. MailGun have tracked a click this morning. In our server logs we see a modified querystring with the error. Viewing the email contents via MailGun shows all the links are perfect before the URL re-write. This particular email was processed via MessageLabs (looking up MX records). I think the issue is with third party spam filters. It's just impossible to explain otherwise.

Comment: Three more failed, all filtered by MessageLabs.

Comment: do you have before and after values for the same outgoing guid?

Comment: I've changed the domain and IP addresses in this example.

Comment: Link in the email: portal.mybusiness.co.uk/redirect/?g=1BDFF192-4595-4550-B2F7-A0809A25C5BD

Comment: Server logs (IIS): 2016-12-01 08:37:59 aa.bb.cc.174 GET /redirect/ g=1OQSS19271-459553-455076-O2S7-N080932N25P5OQ|35|80040e07|Error_converting_data_type_varchar_to_uniqueidentifier. 80 - xx.yy.zz.192 Mozilla/5.0+(compatible;+MSIE+9.0;+Windows+NT+6.1;+WOW64;+Trident/5.0) - 500 0 0 296

Comment: hmmm, a change of that nature would suggest it's not being rewritten but replaced instead. it is possible its being rewritten inside {/redirect/}

Comment: The /redirect/ page is simply taking the querystring parameters from the URL. I have spent a good day re-writing all the code to use a MD5 hash instead. Surprise surprise, all mail relayed via MessageLabs have their hashes modified.

Comment: What I'm now seeing is that a querystring like this g=D29E4EEF51098FF0D67FF3A08E7980D4 is changed to this g=Q29R4RRS5109867SS0Q67SS3N08R798049Q4. The hash is supposed to be 32 characters long. Quite clearly something is wrong with MessageLabs